# How to pass ContentControl Element to CommandParameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, commandparameter

I have a toolbar that show many `Button` with `Image` and `TextBlock`.

Then, I create a CommandManager to manager all `Button`'s commands. So, I want to implement a factory to assign action by `Button`'s `TextBlock`.

This is my xaml and Command function, I try to pass all `Button`'s `Text`, but I don't know how to do.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActionCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Resources/ToolBar/open.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Open"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Button>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Resources/ToolBar/save.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Save"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

ActionManager:

```
public ICommand ActionCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(_onActionCommand); } }

private void _onActionCommand(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    string buttonContent = parameter as string;
    switch (buttonContent)
    {
        case "Open":
            new OpenWindow().ShowDialog();
            break;
        case "Open":
            new Save();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why hard-code the button text? Why not provide properties for the text values for each command? Even better, why switch on the text at all? Why not just provide a separate `ICommand` implementation for each command? Your question is too broad, as there are many different ways you _could_ approach the problem. If you really wanted, you could even bind `CommandParameter={Binding RelativeSource={x:RelativeSource Self}}` and then in the code-behind find the `TextBlock` child to retrieve the `Text` property. Not that I'd advise that, but given your literal question, that'd work.

Comment: Can I find the `TextBlock`'s `Text` property in xaml by RelativeSource?

Comment: No...`RelativeSource` doesn't offer that as an option. You can walk the tree toward ancestors, but not toward descendants. But in code-behind, you can go whichever direction you like. I'm not suggesting you _should_. But you can, if you really insist.

Comment: Thanks, I can do it in code-behind, like you said. But I want to try get children in xaml.

Comment: You can't get children in XAML, not like that. There are examples where you could get them by name, but in the XAML you have shown, naming the `TextBlock` elements wouldn't help, because you would need to somehow use a different name for each time you apply the style. You could probably get it to work by making the buttons into a single `DataTemplate`, but that'd require even more re-working of your current data modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Button` has no concept of "Text" but you could set the `Tag` property to a `string` and pass this one:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActionCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Tag="Open">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Resources/ToolBar/open.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Open"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Button Tag="Save">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Resources/ToolBar/save.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Save"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would have done this way :

```
<Button Tag="AnyUniqueString">
```

and bind the command to it

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Tag}"/>
```

so you are not linked to the text button (u can translate it) - but take care that with one command for all, yo will have trouble manage the refresh and can_execute that will enable/disable your buttons. Perhaps not so complicated to bind each button to separate commands...?

I use it like this in my solution [CBR](https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR/blob/master/CBR/Views/Documents/HomeView.xaml)

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource CbrStandardButton}" Margin="2,10,2,10"
                        Command="{Binding ForwardCommand}" CommandParameter="CatalogNewCommand" >
                    <DockPanel Margin="10">
                        <Image Source="/CBR;component/Resources/Images/32x32/library_new.png" Width="32"></Image>
                        <Label Style="{DynamicResource CbrLabel}"
                               Content="{LocalizationExtension ResModul=CBR, Key=HomeView.LblActionNew, DefaultValue=Start a new library}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource CbrStandardButton}" Margin="2,10,2,10"
                        Command="{Binding ForwardCommand}" CommandParameter="BookOpenCommand" >
                    <DockPanel Margin="10">
                        <Image Source="/CBR;component/Resources/Images/32x32/book/book_read.png" Width="32"></Image>
                        <Label Style="{DynamicResource CbrLabel}"
                               Content="{LocalizationExtension ResModul=CBR, Key=HomeView.LblActionRead, DefaultValue=Read a book}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource CbrStandardButton}" Margin="2,10,2,10"
                        Command="{Binding ForwardCommand}" CommandParameter="SysHelpCommand">
                    <DockPanel Margin="10">
                        <Image Source="/CBR;component/Resources/Images/32x32/book_type/book_type_xps.png" Width="32"></Image>
                        <Label Style="{DynamicResource CbrLabel}"
                               Content ="{LocalizationExtension ResModul=CBR, Key=HomeView.LblActionTutorial, DefaultValue=Quick start tutorial}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for you. But your still need to binding different `CommandParameter` in xaml.

Comment: yes, you can mix both and use the Tag property of your button

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Markup Extension:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456589/Bindable-Converter-Parameter

it allows you to bind command parameter to a xaml property. so you can, for example, put some identifier in the tag field for your button and bind it to the command parameter using the extension. This way you use only one command, only one binding and you get all you need to distinguish buttons in your command handler.

Hope it helps